# Reading through getchar_unlocked -failed case

Tags: c++

This is my code to calculate no. of times A[i]>B[j] such that, 
i < j

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include<cstring>
 using namespace std;
 int main()
  {
  int n,c=0,j=1,i;
  cin>>n;
  int*a,*b;
  a=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
  b=( int*)malloc(sizeof( int)*n);
  for( i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
    cin>>a[i];
   }
  for( i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    cin>>b[i];
  }
  while(j<n)
   {
    for( i=0;i<j;i++)
    {

    if(a[i]>b[j])
    c++;
    }
  j++;
  }
 cout<<c;
return 0;
}
```

This just works fine,and i tried using `getchar_unlocked` to reduce time, but i got a wrong answer in a site. The initial test case showed me correct output, and i did made the same algo work for all cases using `cin` input stream but i failed to do so using `getchar_unlocked` is there any bug in my input function, or where else i am doing it wrong?

My `getchar_unlock` looks like this

```
int readInt()
 {
  char c=getchar_unlocked();
  while(c<'1'||c>'9')
  c=getchar_unlocked();
  int ret=0;
  while(c>='1'&&c<='9')
  {
    ret=ret*10+c-48;
    c=getchar_unlocked();
  }
  return ret;
}
```

P.S: I don't know the failed test case :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `readInt()` doesn't work if there are non-leading zeroes. For example, if the input is `10`, you'll return `1`.

Here's my tried and tested implementation (for non-negative integers only).

```
int get() {
    int res = 0;
    int c;
    do {
        c = getchar_unlocked();
    } while (c <= 32);
    do {
        res = 10*res + c - '0';
        c = getchar_unlocked();
    } while (c > 32);
    return res;
}
```

Also I suggest using `std::vector` instead of calling `malloc` or `new` directly.